# Datagridview: Date From Database to DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datetimepicker

I have two forms where I have to get the date in the dategridview of the first form:

```
private void checkinToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = dgCheckin.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int reserveindex = 10;
    string statindex = dgCheckin.Rows[rowindex].Cells[reserveindex].Value.ToString();
    int roomindex = 5;
    string roomNum = dgCheckin.Rows[rowindex].Cells[roomindex].Value.ToString();

    if (statindex == "Reserved")
    {
        frmCheckIn recheckin = new frmCheckIn(user, true, roomNum);
        recheckin.ShowDialog();
    }
    else if (statindex == "Cancelled")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This " + roomNum + " is already cancelled.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Then the date will put in the datetimepicker in the second form:

```
public void loadReservation()
{
    con.Open();
    string reservetable = "tblReservation";
    string reservequery = "SELECT*FROM tblReservation WHERE RoomNum = '" + this.roomnum + "' AND Status = 'Reserved'";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(reservequery, con);
    da.Fill(ds, reservetable);
    int counter = 0;

    if (counter < ds.Tables[reservetable].Rows.Count)
    {
        string dateuse = ds.Tables[reservetable].Rows[counter]["DateOfUse"].ToString();
        dtpCheckIn.Text = dateuse;
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

But the datetimepicker is not changing/same as what is in the database.

Comment: Where you change the date in the database?

Comment: I don't need to change the date in the database. I want to get the date from datebase to datetimepicker.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem with datetimepicker. You add value to datetimepicker when you do this: `dtpCheckIn.Text = dateuse;`. Then? What's happen?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @erikscandola [Click here for image of the problem](http://min.us/mlSNrUWFqRwth)
@marc_s, I put `if` in the datetimepicker and I did not concatenate together my SQL statement.

Comment: I can't see the image. I see broken image icon.

Comment: [here](http://imgur.com/a/9Wcfc)

Comment: `dtpCheckIn` should be have `value` property. Try this if possible: `dtpCheckIn.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[reservetable].Rows[counter]["DateOfUse"]);`

Comment: I figure out I have this `dtpCheckIn.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();` in the form_load. I added `if` for determine if Check-in or a reserve.

Thanks for the help :)